# compare text to named range in external sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, named-ranges

I have the the following data:

[image]

and I have this data in an another workbook:

[image]
([larger image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoXwR.png))

the formula I am using is:

`=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'C:\path\to\file\John C 05-07-16.xlsx'!Individuals,0)),"NOT-Covered","Covered")`

It was working fine until I tried to get it to refer to a "named range" which is `B4:O40`. I have checked and double checked everything matches up in the named range and confirmed so by evaluating step by step the formula and it properly converts "Individuals" to `B4:O40` but I get a "NOT-Covered" return no matter what text is in the external workbook. I evaluated the formula and it seems to be returning `"#N/A"` for the `ISERROR` function.

Any idea where this is failing and why should be any different when using a named range?

Comment: Match works with one column you range Individuals should be only one column or one row, you have to modify your formula accordingly

Comment: ah, that is what i was missing. I didn't know that limitation with match. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula instead:

```
=IF(AND(ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'your Path'!$B$4:$B$40,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'your Path'!$F$4:$F$40,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'Your Path'!$H$4:$H$40,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'Your Path'!$J$4:$J$40,0)),ISERROR(MATCH(A10,'your Path'!$L$4:$L$40,0)),MATCH(A10,'your Path'!$N$4:$N$40,0))),"Not Covered","Covered")
```

Your path is the address of your book where your array contains the range **B4:O40** but it is split to each column **B4:B40, F4:F40**...
The Function `AND` will determine if match or no match, if no match in all indicated columns, `And` will return `TRUE` which means *Not Covered*.

Comment: thanks! this works. it gets a bit unwieldy because of the path names but I guess that can't be avoided. an array formula wouldn't shorten this would it?

Comment: You can try to do it with array formula, you have the Data